# Connectedness in $R^n$?

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, metric-spaces, connectedness

I have to show that if a set $E$ is a proper subset of $\Bbb R^n$ and is connected, then its closure $\overline E$ is also connected. Is following proof correct?:
Let A,B$\subseteq\Bbb R^n$ be separated sets (i.e, $\overline A$∩B=A∩$\overline B$=∅) such that $\overline E=A∪B$, and suppose that $A≠\varnothing$. Let us prove that B=∅.

Let $a ∈ A$. Since $A∩\overline B=\varnothing$, there exists a neighborhood U of a such that U∩B=∅. Since $a∈\overline E$, then there exists some point $x ∈ E∩U$, so $x ∉ B$, hence $x ∈ E∩A$. Therefore, E∩A≠∅.

Notice that E=(A∩E)∪(B∩E), and A∩E and B∩E are obviously separated. As A∩E≠∅, from the previous paragraph, and E is connected, then B∩E=∅.

Finally, suppose, in order to obtain a contradiction, that B≠∅, and take b ∈ B. By the same arguments as those used in the second paragraph above, switching $A$ and $B$ and $a$ by $b$, we would conclude that B∩E≠∅, contradicting what we have just proved.

Therefore, $B=\varnothing$. This proves that $\overline E$ is connected.

Is this proof mathematically correct? Do I miss any detail?

Comment: Yes, this is correct.